# Check whether BlackBerry maps app is installed

Tags: blackberry

I want to know what API can check if "BlackBerry maps" is installed on a device.
I have a BlackBerry application, and I want to call "BlackBerry maps" from this application, or  throw an error if "BlackBerry maps" hasn't been installed yet.

Answer (score 5):

Above OS 6.0 you need to check for another code module

```
int mh1 = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_lbs"); // OS 4.5 - 5.0
int mh2 = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_maps"); // OS 6.0
if (mh1 == 0 && mh2 == 0) {
   Dialog.alert("BlackBerry Maps not installed");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
m_bbHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("net_rim_bb_lbs");
```

if m_bbHandle > 0 then the module is installed.

net_rim_bb_lbs is BlackBerry Maps.

Here is the link to the [doc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleManager.html)